# How to run a cross-sectional regression for each quarter and industry?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I need to run multiple regressions one for every Industry-quarter combination e.g. a regression for financial companies for every single time period e.g. 1999Q3, 1999Q4, 2000Q1, 2000Q2... etc but also utility companies and every retail company, and every food company etc.

I need to run the regression then collect all the coefficients from the regression into a list so then I can append the list back onto the original data frame so that I have the corresponding coefficients.

For example in the data set below, I would want to run the regression Y = x1 + x2 + x3, I have tried using for loops and nested loops and collecting the coefficients into a matrix but I can't seem to get it to work (I am an R novice!)

I have a panel data set that looks a like the following with the firm name, industry, calendar quarters and a few variables:

```
              `Company Name`  Industry  Quater           Y                x1               x2               x3
               <chr>          <chr>     <chr>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            
              A & M FOOD SE  Food       1985Q1           2.97             16.4             9.23             2.22              
              A & M FOOD SE  Food       1985Q2           5.00             40.2             11.2             3.94              
              A & M FOOD SE  Food       1985Q3           5.71             40.7             12.5             4.66              
              A & M FOOD SE  Food       1985Q4           3.85             39.5             13.0             2.79              
              A & M FOOD SE  Food       1986Q1           3.12             38.9             13.2             1.98              
              A.A. IMPORTIN  Food       1985Q4           12.5             14.0             6.66             0.005             
              A.A. IMPORTIN  Food       1986Q1           13.3             15.0             6.74             0.513              
              A.A. IMPORTIN  Food       1986Q2           13.2             15.0             6.71             0.031             
              A.A. IMPORTIN  Food       1986Q3           13.5             15.2             6.86             0.111             
              C.D. JUMPINGS  Retail     1986Q4           13.1             14.6             7.46             0.241
              C.D. JUMPINGS  Retail     1985Q4           12.5             14.0             6.66             0.005             
              C.D. JUMPINGS  Retail     1986Q1           13.3             15.0             6.74             0.513              
              C.D. JUMPINGS  Retail     1986Q2           13.2             15.0             6.71             0.031             
              Kmart          Retail     1986Q3           13.5             15.2             6.86             0.111
              Kmart          Retail     1986Q4           13.1             14.6             7.46             0.241
              Kmart          Retail     1985Q4           12.5             14.0             6.66             0.005             
              Kmart          Retail     1986Q1           13.3             15.0             6.74             0.513              
              Kmart          Retail     1986Q2           13.2             15.0             6.71             0.031             
              Kmart          Retail     1986Q3           13.5             15.2             6.86             0.111
```

Thank you guys so much I have tried using weird functions from the plm library to lapply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple base R approach is with `split`. `split` divides a `data.frame` from the first argument into a list of `data.frame`s based on the levels of the second argument. Thus, with your sample `data`, `` split(data,data$`Company Name`) `` will result in a list of 4 `data.frame`s.

From there, we can use `lapply` to apply the `lm` function to that subset of the data. Because `lm` has a lot of arguments, it's easier just to define a new function of `x` (called a lambda function).

```
lapply(split(data,data$`Company Name`),
       function(x) lm( Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = x))
```

The formatting is a bit messy, so you could use `sapply` to simplify the results.

```
t(sapply(split(data,data$`Company Name`),
         function(x) lm( Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = x)$coefficients
         )
  )
#              (Intercept)         x1            x2        x3
#A & M FOOD SE   0.5773632 0.01586041 -3.662652e-05 0.9607874
#A.A. IMPORTIN  -3.6117236 0.64295788  1.067509e+00 0.1410264
#C.D. JUMPINGS   1.7123480 0.68601589  1.775447e-01 0.1964184
#Kmart           0.2591970 0.78346288  1.880233e-01 0.0525099
```

If you wanted to do this for two variables, `Company Name` and `Quarter` simply supply a `list` to `split`.

```
t(sapply(split(data,list(data$`Company Name`, data$Quater)),
         function(x) lm( Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = x)$coefficients
         )
  )
```

I can't provide the output, because many of them are empty. Hopefully your dataset is complete. It should look something like this:

```
t(sapply(Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 0, split(data,list(data$`Company Name`, data$Quater))),
          function(x) lm( Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = x)$coefficients
          )
   )
#                     (Intercept) x1 x2 x3
#A & M FOOD SE.1985Q1        2.97 NA NA NA
#A & M FOOD SE.1985Q2        5.00 NA NA NA
#A & M FOOD SE.1985Q3        5.71 NA NA NA
#A & M FOOD SE.1985Q4        3.85 NA NA NA
#A.A. IMPORTIN.1985Q4       12.50 NA NA NA
#C.D. JUMPINGS.1985Q4       12.50 NA NA NA
#Kmart.1985Q4               12.50 NA NA NA
#A & M FOOD SE.1986Q1        3.12 NA NA NA
#A.A. IMPORTIN.1986Q1       13.30 NA NA NA
#C.D. JUMPINGS.1986Q1       13.30 NA NA NA
#Kmart.1986Q1               13.30 NA NA NA
#A.A. IMPORTIN.1986Q2       13.20 NA NA NA
#C.D. JUMPINGS.1986Q2       13.20 NA NA NA
#Kmart.1986Q2               13.20 NA NA NA
#A.A. IMPORTIN.1986Q3       13.50 NA NA NA
#Kmart.1986Q3               13.50 NA NA NA
#C.D. JUMPINGS.1986Q4       13.10 NA NA NA
#Kmart.1986Q4               13.10 NA NA NA
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(`Company Name` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A & M FOOD SE", 
"A.A. IMPORTIN", "C.D. JUMPINGS", "Kmart"), class = "factor"), 
    Industry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Food", 
    "Retail"), class = "factor"), Quater = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L), .Label = c("1985Q1", "1985Q2", "1985Q3", "1985Q4", 
    "1986Q1", "1986Q2", "1986Q3", "1986Q4"), class = "factor"), 
    Y = c(2.97, 5, 5.71, 3.85, 3.12, 12.5, 13.3, 13.2, 13.5, 
    13.1, 12.5, 13.3, 13.2, 13.5, 13.1, 12.5, 13.3, 13.2, 13.5
    ), x1 = c(16.4, 40.2, 40.7, 39.5, 38.9, 14, 15, 15, 15.2, 
    14.6, 14, 15, 15, 15.2, 14.6, 14, 15, 15, 15.2), x2 = c(9.23, 
    11.2, 12.5, 13, 13.2, 6.66, 6.74, 6.71, 6.86, 7.46, 6.66, 
    6.74, 6.71, 6.86, 7.46, 6.66, 6.74, 6.71, 6.86), x3 = c(2.22, 
    3.94, 4.66, 2.79, 1.98, 0.005, 0.513, 0.031, 0.111, 0.241, 
    0.005, 0.513, 0.031, 0.111, 0.241, 0.005, 0.513, 0.031, 0.111
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, I've spent 2 whole days on this!!

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `broom`:

```
library(modelr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

nested <- df %>% 
  group_by(Company.Name, Quater) %>% 
  nest()

#specify regression
country_model <- function(df) {
  lm(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df)
}

#unnest coefficients (only Intercept and one x1 here because most are NA)
nested %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, country_model),
         tidy = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(tidy)

# A tibble: 19 x 9
# Groups:   Company.Name, Quater [18]
   Company.Name  Quater data             model  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>         <chr>  <list>           <list> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A & M FOOD SE 1985Q1 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 2.97e+ 0       NaN       NaN     NaN
 2 A & M FOOD SE 1985Q2 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 5.00e+ 0       NaN       NaN     NaN
 3 A & M FOOD SE 1985Q3 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 5.71e+ 0       NaN       NaN     NaN
 4 A & M FOOD SE 1985Q4 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 3.85e+ 0       NaN       NaN     NaN
 5 A & M FOOD SE 1986Q1 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 3.12e+ 0       NaN       NaN     NaN
 6 A.A. IMPORTIN 1985Q4 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.25e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
 7 A.A. IMPORTIN 1986Q1 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.33e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
 8 A.A. IMPORTIN 1986Q2 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.32e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
 9 A.A. IMPORTIN 1986Q3 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.35e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
10 C.D. JUMPINGS 1986Q4 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.31e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
11 C.D. JUMPINGS 1985Q4 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.25e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
12 C.D. JUMPINGS 1986Q1 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.33e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
13 C.D. JUMPINGS 1986Q2 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.32e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
14 Kmart         1986Q3 <tibble [2 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.35e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
15 Kmart         1986Q3 <tibble [2 x 5]> <lm>   x1          3.81e-16       NaN       NaN     NaN
16 Kmart         1986Q4 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.31e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
17 Kmart         1985Q4 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.25e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
18 Kmart         1986Q1 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.33e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
19 Kmart         1986Q2 <tibble [1 x 5]> <lm>   (Intercept) 1.32e+ 1       NaN       NaN     NaN
```